# mysql database gone away error 2006

Tags: database, mysql, mysql-error-2006

I am importing a sql file of 80 MB, and the mysql database goes away on error 2006.  I increased the connect_timeout=2592000 and wait_timeout = 216000.  What if anything else I need to import the sql file into the db.

It gets stuck at 18236 line.  Can I start import from the 18237 line?

Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue by

```
max_allowed = 16M
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new file with the contents from line 18236 to END, also please check if any insert/update command are there in the beginning. If so, resolve and import the newest file.